# How to manipulate the contents of PopupMenu function?

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, gui-construction

I intend to have a first `PopupMenu` function with a list of parameters `{a,b,c}`. I want a second `PopupMenu` list of contents to change according to what's in the first list like so:

- if the first list has '`a`' selected then the second list is `{1,2,3}`,
- if the first list has `b` selected then the second list is `{4,5,6}`,
- if the first list has '`c`' selected then the second list is `{7,8,9}`.

I have tried the following:

```
Row[{
  PopupMenu[x,{a,b,c},a],
  PopupMenu[y,Piecewise[{{{1,2,3},x==a},{{4,5,6},x==b},{{7,8,9},x==c}}]]
}]
```

but it is not interpreted the way I intended.

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about `Dynamic` here and there.

```
Row[{
  PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], {a, b, c}, a], 
  Dynamic @ PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[y], 
     Switch[x, a, {1, 2, 3}, b, {4, 5, 6}, c, {7, 8, 9}]
  ]
}]
```

Comment: This makes me so happy. I did tried Dynamic just before your post,  but in no way similar to this.